# MySQL - ordering images by votes

Tags: mysql

I haven't used pure mySQL for a while now and looks like I forgot it. Sad story.
Now I have 2 tables - images and votes. Images have a unique id, among others. The votes table only has 2 fields - image id and user id.

I'm trying to get the list of images ordered by number of votes and I'm kinda stuck here. The closest I got is this:

```
SELECT i.uname AS author, i.title, i.time, i.description, i.id, i.extension, v.uid
FROM images as i
LEFT JOIN
votes as v ON i.id = v.iid
```

Which returns all images with the voter ID. If an image has multiple votes, than it's returned more than once.

Can someone please help me with this query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT i.uname AS author, i.title, i.time, i.description, i.id, i.extension, COUNT(v.uid)
FROM images as i
    LEFT JOIN votes as v ON i.id = v.iid
GROUP BY i.uname, i.title, i.time, i.description, i.id, i.extension
ORDER BY Count(v.uid) DESC
```

As suggested, you don't have to `GROUP BY` all your output fields in MySQL -- just use your unique identifier, in this case, i.id.

Comment: +1, but why use group by on so many columns? suggest to use `group by i.id` only

Comment: @SuhelMeman -- I come from a SQL Server background where you have to supply all the fields -- but yes, you are correct, MySQL doesn't require all -- just those unique -- thanks!

Comment: @SuhelMeman: GMTA - see my answer (posted before your comment).

Comment: @sgeddes: where the other fields are functionally dependent on the main grouping field, you don't have to group by them in SQLServer - you can use a summary function (such as MAX) instead. I find it preferable to use the latter approach, as it makes it clearer which fields are actually functionally required for the group.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT i.uname AS author, i.title, i.time, i.description, i.id, i.extension, count(*) votes
FROM images as i
LEFT JOIN votes as v ON i.id = v.iid
group by i.id
order by 7
```

(from lowest to highest - add `desc` after `order by 7` to change the sort order to be from highest to lowest.)